# Materialize CSS Collapsible not expanding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, materialize

I'm trying to add an accordion style collapsible with default behavior to my project.  The header seems to make it to the UI but it will not expand to show the collapsible-body portion.  Any one know how I can make this work?  Or see why it isn't?

Here is my html:

```
<div class="section">
<div ng-repeat="diary in diaries | orderBy:'date' ">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s2 push-s11">
        <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red right-align" ng-click="deleteDiary(diary.id)"><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <h5 class="center-align"><b>{{diary.category}}</b></h5> 
    <h6 class="center-align">{{diary.date}}</h6>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="foodContainer">
    </div>
    <div class="row center-align">
        <ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="accordion" watch>
            <li ng-repeat="food in diary.foods">
                <div class="collapsible-header">{{food.title}}</div>
                <div class="collapsible-body">
                        <label><b>Calories: </b><p>{{food.calories}}</p></label>
                        <label><b>Fat: </b><p>{{food.fat}}</p></label>
                        <label><b>Protein: </b><p>{{food.protein}}</p></label>
                        <label><b>Sodium: </b><p>{{food.sodium}}</p></label>
                        <label><b>Sugars: </b><p>{{food.sugars}}</p></label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller where I initialize the collapsible:

```
"use strict";

app.controller("DiaryCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $location, DiaryFactory, FoodFactory){
$scope.selectedDiary = '';
// $scope.selectedDiary = 'Diary0';
$scope.totalCalories = 0;
$scope.totalFat = 0;
$scope.totalProtein = 0;
$scope.totalSodium = 0;
$scope.totalSugars = 0;
$scope.diaries = [];
$scope.foods = [];

//activate materialize collapsible list 
$('.collapsible').collapsible();

//getMeals
//lists all meals on the diary page
let getAllDiaries = function(){
    DiaryFactory.getDiary($rootScope.user.uid).then(function(FbDiaries) {
        $scope.diaries = FbDiaries;
        console.log('diaries: ', $scope.diaries);
        FoodFactory.getFoodsFB($rootScope.user.uid).then(function(FbFoods){
            console.log('foods from controller', FbFoods);
            FbFoods.forEach(function(food){
                $scope.diaries.forEach(function(diary){
                    // console.log('foods', food);
                    if(food.mealId === diary.id){
                        diary.foods = diary.foods || [];
                        diary.foods.push(food);
                        console.log('foods array on diary', diary.foods);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
getAllDiaries();
```

Here is a screenshot:
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3D8A.png)

Comment: I personally don't use Materialize, but I guess that your problem is this: first, you loads collapsible plugin from materialize and apply those plugin to all `.collapsible` class, then it load Angular. Since your `.collapsible` part is generated by Angular LATER, then you must re-apply materialize plugin again after all the `.collapsible` element have been drawn by Angular.
The simplest is using angular-compatible plugin, like https://material.angularjs.org/latest/. It's a common problem with jQuery based plugin. That's why many develop Angular based plugin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem with React.js and Materialize CSS before.

The reason is exactly like @DennyHio said, Those DOM are not collapsible because they were created by Angular/React after Materialize CSS finished its initialization scrips.

We have to manually "init" those DOM:

```
function afterAngularOrReactHasCreatedAllDOM (){
    // Manually make all DOM with .collapsible collapsible 
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
}
```

Comment: Exactly, I have the same similar problem before with Angular + jQuery UI Datepicker. Simply put, you must call collapsible (and every plugin within Materialize) in your controller/app.js. The BEST WAY is to get angular-compatible plugin, and use dependency injector or directive, it way more easier than have to re-apply whole jQuery plugin